# Why do i receive the error : Set::write: Tag Times in Null w is Protected

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hey guys this is my first time posting so I hope I do this right.

Im trying to run a bit of code in mathematica:

```
VtanList = {};

Do[


 For[j = 1, j <= Length[file], j++,

     test = {data[[i, j]]}[[1, 2]] - {data[[i, j + 1]]}[[1, 2]];
     If[test >= 0,
      peak = j + 5;
      j = Length[file] + 10;
      ]
     ]

    w = Take[data[[i]], {1, peak}];


     , {i, Length[file]/256}]
```

What the data List looks like:

```
data = {{1,2},{3,2},{1,6},{2,4}}
```

When I recieve the error:

```
Tag Times in Null w is Protected.
```

I've tried exiting the kernel, and it doesn't seem to be the classic A+B=C problem I have read about.

I could really use your help, Thanks!!!

Comment: What's `file` is? You did not include it's definition in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a semicolumn after `For[..]`

Without it, Mathematica thinks that `For[..]` and `w = ..` are parts of one continuous expression and, obviously, multiplying a for loop with an assignment operation does not make any sense.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!  Would've spent my thesis trying to figure that one out lol.